# IndexError: list index out of range while attempting to automatically recognize faces using face_recongition

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I was attempting to save the unknown faces in a video and recognize them based on the first frame they appear on for example if an unknown face appears on the frame 14 it should be recognized as "new 14" but i keep getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range" when a new face appears.
So here is my code and the traceback.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2

input_movie = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
length = int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

# Create an output movie file (make sure resolution/frame rate matches input video!)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output_movie = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 29.97, (640, 360))


newimage = face_recognition.load_image_file("anchor.png")
new_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(newimage)[0]

known_faces = [
    new_face_encoding,

]

# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
frame_number = 0


def recog(frame_number, known_faces, face_names):
    toenc = []

    torec = face_recognition.load_image_file(r"New\Unknown%s.jpg" %str(frame_number))

    #if not len(torec):
     #   print("cannot find image")
    #torec = face_recognition.load_image_file(r"New\Unknown%s.jpg" %str(frame_number))
    toenc.append((face_recognition.face_encodings(torec))[0])
    if not len(toenc):
        print("can't be encoded")
    known_faces.append(toenc.pop())
    face_names.append("new %s" %str(frame_number))      

# Load some sample pictures and learn how to recognize them.

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = input_movie.read()
    frame_number += 1

    # Quit when the input video file ends
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    #face_names = []
    for face_encoding in face_encodings:
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        match = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_faces, face_encoding)


        # If you had more than 2 faces, you could make this logic a lot prettier
        # but I kept it simple for the demo
        name = "Unknown"

        face_names.append(name)

    # Label the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        if not name:
            continue

        # Draw a box around the face
        unface = cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if name == "Unknown":
            res = frame[top:bottom, left:right]
            cv2.imwrite(r"New\Unknown%s.jpg" %str(frame_number), res)
            recog(frame_number, known_faces, face_names)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 25), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Write the resulting image to the output video file
    print("Processing frame {} / {}".format(frame_number, length))
    #output_movie.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if( cv2.waitKey(27) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
        break

# All done!
input_movie.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output**

```
In [1]: runfile('D:/project_new/facerec_from_video_file.py', wdir='D:/project_new')
Processing frame 1 / 3291
Processing frame 2 / 3291
Processing frame 3 / 3291
Processing frame 4 / 3291
Processing frame 5 / 3291
Processing frame 6 / 3291
Processing frame 7 / 3291
Processing frame 8 / 3291
Processing frame 9 / 3291
Processing frame 10 / 3291
Processing frame 11 / 3291
Processing frame 12 / 3291
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-4b2c69ca71f8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/project_new/facerec_from_video_file.py', wdir='D:/project_new')

  File "C:\Users\saber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\saber\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/project_new/facerec_from_video_file.py", line 81, in <module>
    recog(frame_number, known_faces, face_names)

  File "D:/project_new/facerec_from_video_file.py", line 35, in recog
    toenc.append((face_recognition.face_encodings(torec))[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: We'd probably need to see where you define `face_recognition.face_encodings()`. I'm curious what the return is on that.

Comment: It's a predefined method in the face_recognition library

Comment: Hmm...check your documentation for `face_recognition.face_encodings()`. I'm wondering if it returns an empty collection if there are no matches, as your code seems to assume the returned collection *has* items in it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a hundred percent sure this reflects to your case, but my experience with `face_recognition` library is that it cannot always *encode* some faces. This usually happens for sideways faces, or if their perspective is too distorted or even if there are too much hair that covers the face.

Personally, [I would suggest adding an exception to handle this](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/178#issuecomment-330004009)

```
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)
if len(encodings) > 0:
    biden_encoding = encodings[0]
else:
   print("No faces found in the image!")
   quit()
```